# Appending "Sir" to list of names? PYTHON

Tags: python, list, append

I already did the first half my task but am struggling with the second:

"Create a second empty array called sir_beatles. Write the pseudocode and python code to copy the contents of the beatles array into the sir_beatles array, and append Sir at the beginning of each name, so the new array contains Sir John, Sir Paul, Sir Ringo, Sir George."

My code

```
size = 4
index = 0
beatles = ["John", "Paul", "Ringo", "George"]

for index in range(len(beatles)):
    print(beatles[index])

sir_beatles = [None] * size

for index in range(0, size):
    sir_beatles[index] = beatles[index]
    print(sir_beatles[index])
```

So it's printing both lists but I am at a total loss with how to add Sir to each index. I tried

**sir_beatles[index].append("Sir")**

but I get the error code *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'*
I tried .insert() as well and have the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with f-string:

```py
beatles = ["John", "Paul", "Ringo", "George"]
sir_beatles = [f"Sir {member}" for member in beatles]

print(sir_beatles) # ['Sir John', 'Sir Paul', 'Sir Ringo', 'Sir George']
```

If, for some reason, you want an explicit `for` loop, then

```py
sir_beatles = []
for member in beatles:
    sir_beatles.append(f"Sir {member}")
```

is an equivalent implementation.

Comment: Took me a second to understand how to implement it into my program, but worked thank you!